# Lubuntu hotspot starts up and then disconnects

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lubuntu, hot-spot

I'm need to use my laptop (with lubuntu 12.04) as a WiFi hotspot.

I created the wifi hotspot via "Create new wireless network" from the network connections menu.

The hotspot comes up and then disconnects. I can see this on my Android phone and tablet. I installed WiFi analyser and shows the new network coming up.
Then suddenly after 2-3 minutes the new WiFi network dissapears from the air.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an android, so you'll have to test this on your own, but I ran across [this page](http://www.ce4arab.com/vb7/showthread.php?t=420240). They say that Android doesn't show ad hoc networks. It finds them in the search, then filters them out.

There's a patch on the site which prevents the filtering.

Again, I haven't tested it, but it might put you on the right track. Let us know if it works for you!

Comment: Hi AlgebraLives,

Comment: @user80115 It seems you tried to post a comment, but only ended up posting the first line.

Answer (score -3):

Your device must be connected to a wired network (i.e., via Ethernet cable).

Comment: No... that has nothing to do with it disappearing...

Comment: Hi Donodo, the Internet flow comes from the wired connection. What I want do do is to serve this viua wifi to my phone/tablet.

Comment: Hi guys; as you pointed out the issue seems to be indeed with Android, not with Lubuntu. I did a quick search on "android hotspot" and there are lots of pages describing the issue and offering solutions, So I will investigate and get back to you with results. Thanks a million!

Comment: You find anything new?